# Can we write bits into .bin file in C?

Tags: c, binary

I want to encode a character into 2 bits, i.e:

```
'A' to 00  
'C' to 01  
'G' to 10  
'T' to 11
```

Now, for example given a file having its contents as `ACGT` whose size is going to be 4 bytes.

I want to read that file and write its corresponding bits into a .bin file whose size eventually would be just 8 bits (1 byte).

i.e:

input text file contents: `ACGT`
output binary file contents: `00011011`

By doing this I would be reducing the size, by 1/4 times of the original size.
Is this possible to implement this in C language?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write this in C (and in many other languages too). The size of the program should be roughly 30 lines.

Comment: No. unless it's always a multiple of 8, because you cannot write less than one byte, so if you have 5 characters your file will be 2 bytes long and you'll have to skip 3 bit pairs. How do you determine which ones to skip if you're using all the available values? You need at least a fixed-size header to tell you how many bit pairs to read.

Comment: @ChatterOne It does say in the question that the size of the input text file is always four bytes.

Comment: @unwind I'm not sure that the size of the file is always 4, probably the questions is poorly worded. And reducing a file size from 4 bytes to 1 looks rather pointless to me. The "ACGT" suggests that the OP wants to deal with [nucleic acid sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_sequence) which are rather long.

Comment: It is impossible to write units of one bit to a file in any languages. The file size should be in unit of 1 byte (8bits)

Comment: the size of the input file can be of any size. I just want to create a new binary file. I need Each character in the input file be represented as only two bits in the new file but not as a binary representation of that character.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm dealing with nucleotides. Any ideal DNA sequence has just four characters A,C,G,T. Since I know that I just have to deal with only four characters I want to create a new binary file with the above combinations I have mentioned.

Comment: yes, it is possible, but you need to decide on a padding scheme or a count prefix because it might be impossible to otherwise tell if the final `1100000` is `TAAA` or `T`

Comment: Can anyone please tell me whether I can write two bits at a time into a binary file?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala would reading 2 bits at a time avoid the problem?

Comment: @shivani_m_ So if I understand the number of characters in the source file is always a multiple of 4. If yes please [edit] your question and make that clear _there_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is not a multiple of 4 always. I have just stated ACGT as the contents of the input file as an example. The contents could be of any size. that is, contains A's T's G's C's any number of times.

Comment: _Can anyone please tell me whether I can write two bits at a time into a binary file?_ There is nothing in the standard C library which allows you to write two individual bits into a file. All functions I know write at least one `char` i.e. one byte. I would collect bits in memory until a certain amount of ful bytes are collected and write them at once.

Comment: What AnttiHaapala is trying to tell you is that writing less than eight bits is not well-defined. If you write four bits, it doesn't mean the other four are "undefined". So now you need to separately encode somehow how many of those bits the reader should read (i.e. how many are significant). There are ways to do that, such as writing a separate header which somehow indicates how many bits follow, but until you solve these things, your encoding is not well-defined.

Comment: @shivani_m_ I think that before going all the way out with this approach you should also stop and consider if there's any actual advantage. The file will have to be read anyway and the in-program data structure will most likely take the some amount of RAM to be loaded. The only difference would be disk space and honestly, is that a real problem nowadays?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala padding is impossible since all 4 of 2-bit values are in use. So the only option is count. It could be 1 byte number which specifies how many bit pairs are significant in the last byte or just 4 byte size_t for total characters (assuming the sequence is shorter then 4B characters).

Comment: @Dmitry on the contrary, padding is very much possible. See for example PKCS#7; while by default defined for 8x8 bit blocks, the same would work for 4x2 bit blocks alike, the only restriction is that `00` be considered a length 4 and a final `0x00` byte be followed by an extra `0x00` byte.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but it will not be shorter then a sigle byte which specifies how many bit pairs are significant in the last byte. My point is that you can't add padding here without additional overhead.

Comment: @Dmitry but it is, because the final 1, 2 and 3 bases are terminated within the same byte and only a full quartet receives an extra padding byte, which gives an average 2 bit extra over the unpadded ones.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ah, ok I understand, it for average case.

Answer (score 1):

Following code demonstrates what you need to do. It encodes/decodes according to your specification but only in memory not in a file. The code needs to be adapted for encoding/decoding a file.

**Format of encoded bytes:**

The first 4 bytes (or 8 bytes according to the platform) contain the number of encoded characters ("ACGTA" would be 5 characters) in big endian (or little endian format according ton the platform). The bytes after that contain the encoded characters according to your specification.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void encode(const char *input, unsigned char *output)
{
  size_t size = strlen(input);
  memcpy(output, &size, sizeof (size_t));
  output += sizeof(size_t);
  size_t outputindex = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; )
  {
    unsigned char byte = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 4 && i < size; j++)
    {
      unsigned char value;
      switch (input[i++])
      {
      case 'A':
        value = 0;
        break;
      case 'C':
        value = 1;
        break;
      case 'G':
        value = 2;
        break;
      case 'T':
        value = 3;
        break;
      default:
        printf("Input error, invalid char '%c' encountered\n", input[i - 1]);
        exit(1);
      }

      byte |= (value << ((3 - j) * 2));
    }

end:
    output[outputindex++] = byte;
  }
}

void decode(const unsigned char *input, char *output)
{
  size_t size;
  memcpy(&size, input, sizeof(size_t));
  input += sizeof(size_t);
  size_t inputindex = 0;

  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < size;)
  {
    unsigned char ch = input[inputindex++];

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      unsigned char b = (ch >> ((3 - j) * 2)) & 0x3;
      output[i++] = "ACGT"[b];
      if (i >= size)
        break;
    }
  }

  output[i] = 0;
}

void printhexencoded(unsigned char *input)
{
  size_t size;
  memcpy(&size, input, sizeof(size_t));
  size = (size + 3) / 4;
  input += sizeof(size_t);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("%02x", input[i]);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  const char testdata[] = "ACGTCGTAACGATACTGCTAA";

  printf("Encoding %s\n", testdata);
  unsigned char encodedbytes[100];
  encode(testdata, encodedbytes);

  printf("Encoded bytes in hexadecimal: ");
  printhexencoded(encodedbytes);
  printf("\n");

  char decodedbytes[100];
  decode(encodedbytes, decodedbytes);

  printf("Decoded bytes %s\n", decodedbytes);  

  if (strcmp(testdata, decodedbytes) != 0)
    printf("Test failed.");
  else
    printf("Test succeeded.");    
}
```

Disclaimer: this code has been barely tested and there is no bounds checking done at all. It is assumed that the input contains only characters in the set `[ACGT]` if any other characters is encountered, the program exits.